# Стилизация select/option под Contact Form 7

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form7, html-select

Собственно, имеется форма обратной связи с возможностью выбора города в выпадающем списке. Реализовано посредством плагина Contact Form 7. Данный список реализуется плагином тегами `select`/`option`. Собственно, вопрос в том, как стилизовать этот выпадающий список? Если делать это с помощью скриптов, не будет ли конфликта с обертками инпутов, которые создает Contact Form 7?

Answer (score 1):

Удалось подружить Contact Form 7 со скриптом jQuery Form Styler. Пока багов не выявлено. Можно пользоваться. Скрипт и документация http://dimox.name/jquery-form-styler/[image: введите сюда описание изображения]